# Show/hide BottomNavigationView on scroll in CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to use both `AppBarLayout` and `BottomNavigationLayout` in a single `CoordinatorLayout` and I'm having difficulties hiding the `BottomNavigationLayout` as required by the [material guideline](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior).

I mean something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_insetEdge="top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see, I also have a `FrameLayout` that's used to contain a fragment with the actual content. Currently there are no default/built-in behaviors for the `BottomNavigationView` - neither for the view itself, nor for its siblings. The existing `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` handles the content view in coordination with the appbar but ignores other siblings.

I am looking for a solution to hide and show both the appbar and the bottom navigation view on scroll.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a day or two of searching I settled with a custom [`Behavior`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html) attached to the `BottomNavigationView`. Its main idea is to detect when the BottomNavigationView's sibling is scrolled so that it can hide the BottomNavigationView. Something like this:

```
public class BottomNavigationBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

    public BottomNavigationBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public BottomNavigationBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, View dependency) {
        boolean dependsOn = dependency instanceof FrameLayout;
        return dependsOn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        if(dy < 0) {
            showBottomNavigationView(child);
        }
        else if(dy > 0) {
            hideBottomNavigationView(child);
        }
    }

    private void hideBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
        view.animate().translationY(view.getHeight());
    }

    private void showBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
        view.animate().translationY(0);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using simple [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html), obtained using the child views's [`animate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate()) method. This leads to a simple animation that doesn't really match the `AppBarLayout`'s behavior but it's decent enough to look good and at the same time it's simple enough to implement.

I expect that at some point the Android team will add a default Behavior for the BottomNavigationView in the support library so I don't think it's reasonable to invest a lot more time to exactly duplicate the AppBarLayout's behavior.

**edit** (April 2018): see the comments section for a minor clarification about `onStartNestedScroll` and `onNestedPreScroll` and their new versions.

Comment: Thank you! Btw **onStartNestedScroll** and **onNestedPreScroll** are now deprecated. Both need `int type` as the last parameter ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Jokus I haven't used the BottomNavBar since this post but i'll try to take a look and edit as needed. Thanks for the clarification - it could be useful for others.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/scroll-your-bottom-navigation-view-away-with-10-lines-of-code-346f1ed40e9e

Comment: What do i do if I want the opposite. A header layout going off the screen.

Comment: @Debjit if you mean the App Bar Layout then you could use its default behaviour -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.Behavior

Comment: @stan0 No not app bar. I have a layout on top which needs to quick return.

Comment: Support library has an integrated hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior doing the same.

Comment: This is not Material. you are using support library.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/behavior/HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior). This behavior works in basically the same way, but also handles cancelling any existing animations that are running which should be better for performance.

Comment: This looks promising! It's probably the correct way to do it nowadays but unfortunately I don't have the time to test it now. So I hope other users would be able to test and upvote in order to improve this question/answer.

Comment: Have you tested it till now? If yes, can you please tell me how to use this?

Comment: Take a look at the source, it's pretty simple. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/behavior/HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior.java