# Position children inside CoordinatorLayout without containers

Tags: android

My layout:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout />

    <BottomNavigationView />

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

This bottom navigation has a CoordinatorLayout.Behavior that manages hiding it when the fragment displayed in the `FrameLayout` is scrolled.

I do not understand how I could prevent the `FrameLayout` overlapping with the bottom navigation since I cannot place them in another layout because the `BottomNavigationView` needs to be a direct child for the `CoordinatorLayout` behavior.

As a workaround, when I set a bottom padding on the `FrameLayout`, that works, but then the space remains empty when the bottom navigation is hidden, changing it with an animation would be possible but seems like quite some work.

Is there really no way I can align children in a `CoordinatorLayout` in a way that they don't overlap?

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631542/show-hide-bottomnavigationview-on-scroll-in-coordinatorlayout-with-appbarlayout

Comment: @QuentinMenini Yes, this is what my behavior for hiding the bottom navigation is based on. However, the CoordinatorLayout acts like a FrameLayout, placing the BottomNavigation at the bottom via gravity, but overlapping the FrameLayout. A workaround would be always hiding the BottomNavigation when scrolled to the bottom of the frame, this way the overlap would not be noticeable. I was hoping for a more solid solution though.