# Showing and hiding BottomAppBar on scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components

I'm trying to implement `BottomAppBar` where I would handle the navigation of a `WebView`.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar$Behavior"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:fabAttached="true"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:tint="#fff"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_bar"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Everything works fine but I want to be able to show and hide the `BottomAppBar` when the users scrolls down and up respectively just as is the behavior [here](https://material.io/design/assets/1gaSrddolFHd8BwOioeYz0ODiyEhCevtn/behavior-scroll.mp4).

I couldn't find a tutorial on that anywhere so has someone implemented a solution on it?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42631543/7915814) question, it's for `BottomNavigationView` but I think it's applicable to you

Answer (score 9):

Try settting `app:hideOnScroll` without setting `app:layout_behavior` or `app:layout_scrollFlags`. And remove the `AppBarLayout` parent view so the `BottomAppBar` is just a direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: You should also put the content (in this case your ConstraintLayout) in a NestedScrollView. That's what allows the CoordinatorLayout to receive the scroll events and dispatch to the BottomAppBar behavior which will hide it.

Comment: @Cameron, can you please share code fragments to help me understand better? I have a RecyclerView inside ConstraintLayout inside a Fragment, which site in a FrameLayout. 

How do I use NestedScrollView here?

Comment: You need to have a `CoordinatorLayout`, with the `RecyclerView` (or something that implements `NestedScrollingChild`) and the `BottomAppBar` as direct children. Then you just set `app:hideOnScroll` on the `BottomAppBar` to enable that feature. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

HideOnScroll does not work with ScrollView instead, use NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this, when you wont to hide or show your BottomNavigationView or BottomAppBar add one of this line in your method of Scrolling :

```
..
int height = bottomAppBar.getHeight();

//Hide
bottomAppBar.clearAnimation();
bottomAppBar.animate().translationY(height).setDuration(200);
//Show
bottomAppBar.clearAnimation();                    
bottomAppBar.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(200);
..
```