# Implementing app:hideOnScroll for BottomAppBar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, android-bottomappbar

I have an app with the one Activity, many Fragments model, where several Fragments have a RecyclerView to show cards with content. I also have implemented the BottomAppBar from Material Design 2.0, and everything is fine except when the AppBar blocks the last CardView in the RecyclerView.

In terms of layout, I have a RecyclerView inside ConstraintLayout inside a Fragment, which sits in a FrameLayout in the main activity.

The documentation shows that for the BottomAppBar to be hidden on Scroll, [we need to implement RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomAppBar.md#hide-on-scroll). There is [one question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378848/showing-and-hiding-bottomappbar-on-scroll) where the answer has stated the same as well, but there seems to be no actual documentation or examples to demonstrate how this is to be done, except for [this article on Medium](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-behavior-fbfbc3a30568), which uses the NestedScrollView in an Activity directly, holding a CoordinatorLayout which holds a ConstraintLayout.

Note: I think it also works on magic, because duplicating the layout in my fragment doesn't have any effect at all in my app.

How do I use NestedScrollView here?

PS : I need to have the TextView, as I set the RecyclerView to VISIBILITY.GONE and set the TextView to VISIBLE when I have no data to display.

**Fragment Layout**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.domain.APPNAME.Fragments.FragmentList">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewIncident"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="No Incidents to display"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/uberLayout"
    tools:context=".APPNAME">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_white_24dp"
            app:hideOnScroll="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        </android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/brightred"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="465dp" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you shouldn't put the `BottomAppBar` and the `FloatingActionButton` in a separate `CoordinatorLayout`. Ditch the `CoordinatorLayout` they're in, the `ConstraintLayout` around your `FrameLayout` and that may already solve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/uberLayout"
    tools:context=".APPNAME">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_white_24dp"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/brightred"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'm using a similar layout, the only difference being a `<fragment>` instead of a `<FrameLayout>`, and the BottomAppBar hides on scroll just fine. We don't need to use a `NestedScrollView`, if our scrolling content is a `RecyclerView` anyway, because `RecyclerView` implements [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild).

> This interface should be implemented by View subclasses that wish to support **dispatching nested scrolling operations** to a cooperating parent ViewGroup.