# How to override CoordinatorLayout.Behavior without breaking CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-bottomappbar

I'm creating an Android application and I want to hide the `BottomAppBar` (it has a fab anchored on the center) whenever I scroll the `RecyclerView` who's inside the fragment of my activity without changing the layout of the `BottomAppBar`.

Following some online guides, I've created my own class that extends `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` and override `onStartNestedScroll` & `onNestedPreScroll` so that the `BottomAppBar` get hidden whenever I scroll.

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...>
    ...
    <android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="15dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```java
BottomAppBar bab = (BottomAppBar) findViewById(R.id.bottom_app_bar);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) bab.getLayoutParams();
BottomNavigationBehavior bnb = new BottomNavigationBehavior();
layoutParams.setBehavior(bnb);



class BottomNavigationBehavior<V extends View> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>{

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull V child, @NonNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target, int axes, int type) {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull V child, @NonNull View target, int dx, int dy, @NonNull int[] consumed, int type) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
        child.setTranslationY(Math.max(0f, Math.min(child.getHeight(),child.getTranslationY() + dy)));
    }
}
```

Without the custom class, this is the (desired) result (but the scrolling-hiding behavior is obviously not working)

[image: Desired layout]

With the custom class, this is the (unwanted) result (but the scrolling-hiding behavior does work)

[image: Undesired layout]

I thought that since I'm not modifying the `layoutParams` parameters but only the behavior the layout should be the same, but obviously there's something I'm missing...

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only glanced through source code, but drawing cutout is part of default [`BottomAppBar.Behavior`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBar.java#L822).

Your best bet is having your custom behavior extend it instead of empty `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` (or at least copy relevant code for drawing cutout) and work Your way up from there.

By the way, is `app:hideOnScroll` ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378848/showing-and-hiding-bottomappbar-on-scroll)) not working for You?

Comment: Of course I forgot to add `app:hideOnScroll` ...

However extending `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` as you suggested wasn't working for some reason.
Thank you for your great answer!