# When scroll bottom navigation bar does not hide - BottomNavigationBehavior

Tags: android, behavior, bottomnavigationview

i want to hide bottom navigation bar so i am using bottom navigation behavior 
it works when i had other code but in this it seems not working i tried but bottom navigation bar won't hide
Here is the code

```
 package com.blipclap.creativegraphy.Helper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;

import static java.lang.Float.parseFloat;

public class BottomNavigationBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior {

    public BottomNavigationBehaviour() {
    }

    public BottomNavigationBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull View child, @NonNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target, int axes, int type) {
        return axes== ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull View child, @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);
        child.setTranslationY(Math.max(0f,
                Math.min(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(child.getHeight())),child.getTranslationY()+dyConsumed)));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        if (dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout)
            updateSnackbar(child,dependency);
        return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, child, dependency);
    }

    private void updateSnackbar(View child, View dependency) {
        if (dependency.getLayoutParams()instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) dependency.getLayoutParams();

            params.setAnchorId(child.getId());
            params.anchorGravity= Gravity.TOP;
            params.gravity=Gravity.TOP;
            dependency.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
    }
}
```

this is my layout content layout i tried changing relative layout but app unfortunately stops so i can't change it

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.blipclap.creativegraphy.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior=".Helper.BottomNavigationBehavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/background_dark"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"></android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this are my 3 fragments i am using when i scroll bottom navigation bar does not hide
Category

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.blipclap.creativegraphy.Fragment.CategoryFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_category"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

daily popular

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.blipclap.creativegraphy.Fragment.CategoryFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_trending"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

recent

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.blipclap.creativegraphy.Fragment.CategoryFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_recent"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this code is not working for me what should i do any solution

refrence

[bottom navigation behavior reference 1](https://android.jlelse.eu/scroll-your-bottom-navigation-view-away-with-10-lines-of-code-346f1ed40e9e)

[bottom navigation behavior reference 2](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/bottom-navigation-behavior-388b9b206667)

[bottom navigation behavior reference 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8NTs-6RbHE&feature=youtu.be)

i followed the last one but its not working

Comment: Can you clarify, you provided the code from the first link, so when you scroll, the BottomNavigationView doesn't hide? What's happening?

Comment: Sorry, when i scroll it, bottom navigation doesn't hide it looks like something i am doing wrong but can't figure out what am i missing

Comment: is it because of viewpager ?

Comment: No, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things:

**1)** You should not override `onNestedScroll`, it should be `onNestedPreScroll`, delete `onNestedScroll` and replace it with that:

```
@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull View child, @NonNull View target, int dx, int dy, @NonNull int[] consumed, int type) {
    super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
    child.setTranslationY(Math.max(0f,
            Math.min(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(child.getHeight())),child.getTranslationY()+dy)));
}
```

**2)** In your XML file, you put

```
app:layout_behavior=".Helper.BottomNavigationBehavior"
```

And your class name is

```
BottomNavigationBehaviour
```

As you can see one is Behavi**our**, and the other is Behav**ior**, normally it should throw a runtime error, and the app shouldn't be able to run, it may be a typo on your part, but I mentioned it just in case.

But be aware that this code has a bug, if you try to scroll all the way down or up, the `RecyclerView` item will not be clickable for a couple of seconds, I have a [similar bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215898/recyclerview-not-clickable-for-several-seconds). For now, my choice is to use animation to hide the `BottomNavigationView` as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42631543/7915814) post.

**EDIT:**

It's possible that the behaviour is not applied because `BottomNavigationView` is not a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`, so you can either delete the `RelativeLayout` entirely or take the `BottomNavigationView` out:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.blipclap.creativegraphy.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior=".Helper.BottomNavigationBehavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/background_dark"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: it's like it has no effect at all

Comment: @vinit I can't test your code right now, but meanwhile try to implement the hiding of the `BottomNavigationView` using the animation method that I linked, at least it doesn't have the bug.

Comment: @vinit I think it may be due to the fact that `BottomNavigationView` is not a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout` so the behaviour is not applied, try to delete the `RelativeLayout`, so that `BottomNavigationView` becomes a direct child.

Comment: @vinit or actually, just take the `BottomNavigationView` out of the `RelativeLayout` and add `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to it, I'll edit the answer

Comment: thanks a lot this thing worked you were right behaviour was not applied because BottomNavigationView is not a direct child of CoordinatorLayout when you told i noticed it thanks once again

Comment: @baderkhane Happy to help! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**BottomLayoutBehavior.java**

```
package com.utility.behaviour;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;

public class BottomLayoutBehavior<V extends View> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V> {

    public BottomLayoutBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull V child,
                                       @NonNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target, int axes, int type) {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull V child,
                                  @NonNull View target, int dx, int dy, @NonNull int[] consumed, int type) {
        child.setTranslationY(Math.max(0f, Math.min(child.getHeight(), child.getTranslationY() + dy)));
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.utility.viewpager.SwipeOnOffViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bnvHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/home_tab_bg"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/home_tab_bg"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="com.utility.behaviour.BottomLayoutBehavior"
        app:menu="@menu/home_bottom_navigation_items" />
    <!--app:itemBackground="@drawable/home_bottom_bar_gap"-->
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

NB: `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` & `app:layout_behavior="com.utility.behaviour.BottomLayoutBehavior"` is mandatory.